# Запустить mediascanner android

Tags: android, java

не получается запустить  mediascanner на KitKat/ nexus7. пытаюсь запустить его так:

```
sendBroadcast (
                     new Intent(Intent.ACTION____MEDIA____MOUNTED,
                     Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))
                     );

но в ответ система бросает exception. вот что написал:
```

`12-01 20:50:57.862: E/AndroidRuntime(18228): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=18228, uid=10097`
вообще не понимаю в чём дело. на 2,3,6 андроиде это запускается ок.

Comment: Судя по ошибке в логе, Вам необходимо использовать какие-то permissons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

такого permission'a не существует. гугление и поиск на stackoverflow подсказало мне что это какойто баг то ли самого устройства nexus 7 , толи операционной системы kitkat. проблему запуска mediascanner'a решил запуском метода:

```
`MediaScannerConnection.scanFile`
```

к сожалению этот метод не запускает поиск сканера по всей системе как хотелось бы. а требует в параметрах массив с путями определенных файлов. 
в общем проблема решена

Answer (score 2):

привет @argamidon

https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/78852/

> Grant dev tools system permission to
>   trigger media-scan service
>
> Google add the action
>   ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNT into the list of
>   protected boradcast, so that ordinary
>   apps cannot trigger media scanning by
>   directly sending the action out. The
>   system built-in dev tool is granted
>   system permission so that it will not
>   crash when executing media scaning
>   tools.

по русски - начиная с `KitKat ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNT`  добавлен в список защищенных и на него нужны права, которых у обычных приложений нет.
попробуй вот [эту](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21085069) ссылку для KitKat